# Regex for sorting

Tags: regex, sorting, kotlin

Hello I need a help with writing a regex to sort an house addresses.

I have list of adresses like: `val list = listOf("1", "5b", "1b", "1c", "1-10", "5", "5a", "10"))`

After sorting it : result should be :

`1, 1-10, 1b, 1c, 5, 5a, 5b, 10`

Comment: If you would like to sort by the first int number, the result would be `[1, 1b, 1c, 1-10, 5b, 5, 5a]`

Comment: How to achieve this? Is there a function which will help me to split it?

Comment: I don't think your question is clear. Well, if you just want to split a string with commas optionally wrapped with whitespaces and sort the items in the resulting list by the first chunk of digits, you may use `var results = s.split("\\s*,\\s*".toRegex()).sortedBy { "\\d+".toRegex().find(it)?.value?.toInt() }`

Comment: Ok, I see you also want to apply natural sort for each group of items that start with the same number?

Comment: I mean these string data are strings - array of strings like for example addresses for homes and I would like to sort them

Comment: Then join the items, append `.joinToString(", ")`

Comment: Ok, try `s.split(", ").sortedWith(compareBy({ "^\\d+".toRegex().find(it)?.value?.toInt() }, { it })).joinToString(", ")`. I got a `1, 1-10, 1b, 1c, 5, 5a, 5b, 10` output. If the `^` is used, it will only match first digit chunk at the start of a string.  I assume the split items will always start with a digit.

Comment: @CallMePedro why should `1-10` appear before `1a`? Should all `n-n` appear before `n-a` for the same `n` (where `n` is a number and `a` is a letter)?

Comment: Cause 1 is before than 1a so thats why 1-10 is earlier. ```n-n``` won't happen in this scenario it will be consumed as ```n```.

Comment: Wiktor please note that I am using an array not a single string. But I am getting the idea how it works

Comment: Please update the question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Wiktor I just edited

Comment: No, `val list = listOf(1, 5b, 1b, 1c, 1-10, 5, 5a, 10)` does not compile.

Comment: Ok that was stupid mistake :D. Sorry

Comment: Then `list.sortedWith(compareBy({ "^\\d+".toRegex().find(it)?.value?.toInt() }, { it })).joinToString(", ")` works

Comment: It returned ```[1, 5b, 1b, 1c, 1-10, 5, 5a, 10]```

Comment: No, it [returns a string](https://rextester.com/XSQD22299)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to match your changed question:

```
fun sortMyThing(list: List<String>): List<String> {
    val cmp = Comparator<String> { a, b ->
        val intA  = a.replace("(\\d+).*".toRegex(), "$1").toInt()
        val intB = b.replace("(\\d+).*".toRegex(), "$1").toInt()
        if (intA == intB) {
            a.compareTo(b) //otherwise 1-10 goes after 1c
        } else {
            intA - intB
        }
    }
    return list.sortedWith(cmp)
}
```

I get result: `1, 1-10, 1b, 1c, 5, 5a, 5b, 10`

Comment: Edited and added 1b, my bad I missed it

Comment: Ok and what with strings like ```10```, ```20```? Answer is wrong then. Of course I added only few "data examples" but in general with other values sorting is incorrect

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve then? This gives result what you wanted as per "Result should be" in your question. If you want different result, ask for it.

Comment: I want to achieve working sorting, nothing else. In question I added sample of data. In general I want sorting to work on strings.

Comment: This sorting works on your sample data, does it not?

Comment: Since your question is now clear, modified question.

Comment: Thank you, greetings :)